# Regex search lookaround

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy

I have a logfile generated for this script I've written and I want to look for errors.

The logfile looks like this:

```
24/05/2017 07:39:55 PM | DEBUG | Reading config file "FRGD-1_1.cfg". | main.py:81 - set_configparser()
...
...
24/05/2017 07:39:55 PM | DEBUG | Reading config file "FRGD-1_10.cfg". | main.py:81 - set_configparser()    
...
...
24/05/2017 08:39:55 PM | DEBUG | Reading config file "RFGD-1_5.cfg". | main.py:81 - set_configparser()    
...    
25/05/2017 09:53:47 PM | ERROR | KeyError. There is an issue with the config file for this download. Please check the config file for errors. | script.py:137 - main()    
...
... 
24/05/2017 10:39:55 PM | DEBUG | Reading config file "DPGD-4_15.cfg". | main.py:81 - set_configparser()  
...
...
24/05/2017 11:39:55 PM | DEBUG | Reading config file "ZXTD-3_1.cfg". | main.py:81 - set_configparser()
...  
25/05/2017 03:53:47 AM | ERROR | KeyError. There is an issue with the config file for this download. Please check the config file for errors. | script.py:137 - main()    
...
...
24/05/2017 07:39:55 PM | DEBUG | Reading config file "FRGD-1_1.cfg". | main.py:81 - set_configparser()
...
...  
24/05/2017 07:39:55 PM | DEBUG | Reading config file "FRGD-1_10.cfg". | main.py:81 - set_configparser()
```

I want to capture all the names of the config files which have thrown an error.

To identify the lines, I look for lines which have:

```
DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS PM | DEBUG | Reading config file "<file_name>.cfg".
```

directly before:

```
DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS PM | ERROR |
```

In the example above, they are "RFGD-1_5.cfg" and "ZXTD-3_1.cfg".

I am using Python to run this regex, as such I have concatenated the whole file to a single line and used the following regex

```
'(?<=Reading config file "(.{13})").+?\| ERROR \|'.
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intuitively, one would say to match the last `config file` before `ERROR`. With the newer `regex` module, a variable lookbehind is possible like so:

```
import regex as re
rx = re.compile(r'''
                (?<=config\ file\ "([^"]+)"(?s:.*?))
                \|\ ERROR\ \|
                ''', re.VERBOSE)

print(rx.findall(string))
# ['RFGD-1_5.cfg', 'ZXTD-3_1.cfg']
```

See [**a demo on regexstorm.com**](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3Dconfig%5C%20file%5C%20%22%28%5B%5E%22%5D%2B%29%22%28%3Fs%3A.*%3F%29%29%0D%0A%5C%7C%5C%20ERROR%5C%20%5C%7C&i=24%2F05%2F2017%2007%3A39%3A55%20PM%20%7C%20DEBUG%20%7C%20Reading%20config%20file%20%22FRGD-1_1.cfg%22.%20%7C%20main.py%3A81%20-%20set_configparser%28%29%0D%0A24%2F05%2F2017%2007%3A39%3A55%20PM%20%7C%20DEBUG%20%7C%20Reading%20config%20file%20%22FRGD-1_10.cfg%22.%20%7C%20main.py%3A81%20-%20set_configparser%28%29%20%20%20%20%0D%0A...%20%20%20%20%0D%0A24%2F05%2F2017%2008%3A39%3A55%20PM%20%7C%20DEBUG%20%7C%20Reading%20config%20file%20%22RFGD-1_5.cfg%22.%20%7C%20main.py%3A81%20-%20set_configparser%28%29%20%20%20%20%0D%0A...%20%20%20%20%0D%0A25%2F05%2F2017%2009%3A53%3A47%20PM%20%7C%20ERROR%20%7C%20KeyError.%20There%20is%20an%20issue%20with%20the%20config%20file%20for%20this%20download.%20Please%20check%20the%20config%20file%20for%20errors.%20%7C%20script.py%3A137%20-%20main%28%29%20%20%20%20%0D%0A...%20%20%20%20%0D%0A24%2F05%2F2017%2010%3A39%3A55%20PM%20%7C%20DEBUG%20%7C%20Reading%20config%20file%20%22DPGD-4_15.cfg%22.%20%7C%20main.py%3A81%20-%20set_configparser%28%29%20%20%0D%0A...%20%20%20%20%0D%0A24%2F05%2F2017%2011%3A39%3A55%20PM%20%7C%20DEBUG%20%7C%20Reading%20config%20file%20%22ZXTD-3_1.cfg%22.%20%7C%20main.py%3A81%20-%20set_configparser%28%29%20%20%20%20%0D%0A25%2F05%2F2017%2003%3A53%3A47%20AM%20%7C%20ERROR%20%7C%20KeyError.%20There%20is%20an%20issue%20with%20the%20config%20file%20for%20this%20download.%20Please%20check%20the%20config%20file%20for%20errors.%20%7C%20script.py%3A137%20-%20main%28%29%20%20%20%20%0D%0A...%20%20%20%20%0D%0A24%2F05%2F2017%2007%3A39%3A55%20PM%20%7C%20DEBUG%20%7C%20Reading%20config%20file%20%22FRGD-1_1.cfg%22.%20%7C%20main.py%3A81%20-%20set_configparser%28%29%20%20%20%20%0D%0A24%2F05%2F2017%2007%3A39%3A55%20PM%20%7C%20DEBUG%20%7C%20Reading%20config%20file%20%22FRGD-1_10.cfg%22.%20%7C%20main.py%3A81%20-%20set_configparser%28%29&o=xs) (click on *Table*).

---

A bit of an explanation here:

```
(?<=             # a pos. lookbehind              
    config file  # config file literally
    \"([^\"]+)\" # capture anything between "..."
    (?s:.*?)     # turns on single line mode (dot matches all including newline), 
                 # lazily, expanded as needed
)                # closing lookbehind
\| ERROR \|      # | ERROR | literally
```

Note, that the whitespaces need to be escaped as well in `verbose mode` and that the double quotes **do not** need to be escaped (makes it only pretty on `StackOverflow`).
This only works with the newer `regex` module as the lookbehind can be of any length.

Comment: Hi Jan. Thanks for your time. This works just like magic. Could I ask you to clarify what are you doing in this section: (?s:.*?)

Comment: @jerry_doe: Yup, see the modified answer.

Comment: Thank you so much Jan. That was brilliant. I am very grateful.